# Using a list from another fuction will pass it empty, why?

Tags: python, list, function

I'm returning 5 lists from a function in python, then I'm defining another function as such:

```
def excel_parser(list_titles, list_links, list_prices, num_elem_titles, num_elem_link):
```

I then call the function and I tried everyway, this is the only one that gives a result, but the lists get emptied, they instead contain items in them.

```
excel_parser(list_titles=[], list_links=[], list_prices=[], num_elem_titles=[], num_elem_link=[])
```

This is how I use the functions inside the second function:

```
    print(len(list_titles))

row = 3

for line in list_titles:
    if row <= num_elem_titles:
        Foglio_Annunci["B" + str(row)] = line
        row += 1

row = 3

for line in list_links:
    if row <= num_elem_link:
        Foglio_Annunci["C" + str(row)] = line
        row += 1

row = 3

for line in list_prices:
    if row <= num_elem_link:
        Foglio_Annunci["D" + str(row)] = line
        row += 1

row = 3
```

Comment: We need to see more of your code to understand. Please include a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=minimum+reproducible+example)

Comment: Unfortunately, it is hard to know more about your problem with what is shared already. Can you please show more of your code so readers can try to replicate it on their end to see where the problem lies. I did notice, however that you seem to be setting a mutable (list) as a default argument in your method definition for `excel_parser` which carries some bad side effects. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) to see why that should be avoided in Python. It might help with your issue.

Comment: @idjaw I added the code where I use these lists inside the second function :)

Comment: Can you take a look at this and let me know if it helps you: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments

Comment: @ZaidAlShattle I'm trying to get a list with all its items and use it in the second function, how can I do that? I'm studying and working, I'm doing really bad on anxiety and I read the link you gave me and didn't understand much. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

In python, having lists as a parameters is almost certainly **not** what you are trying to do, as per [here](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments):

> A new list is created once when the function is defined, and the same list is used in each successive call.

Thus, if you want to take that method, using this method instead:

```
def append_to(element, to=None):
if to is None:
    to = []
to.append(element)
return to
```

Would turn out with the correct behavior, in general anything put in the brackets for the function (defining a list for example, or calling another function), is called **only once** at the program startup, and is never called again.

So to conclude, instead of:

```
excel_parser(list_titles=[], list_links=[], list_prices=[], num_elem_titles=[], num_elem_link=[])
```

use:

```
excel_parser(list_titles=None, ...)
```

and inside the function for each one:

```
if list_titles is None:
    to = []
```

Comment: A clever way will be to use `or` instead of `if` . `list_titles = list_titles or []`.

Comment: I did the code and rerun it, it doesn't give errors, but the excel files is exmpty, so the functions are still empty. leng(list_titles) is 0 for example. What is wrong? I added my code to your answer.

Comment: @MichelangeloAmorusoManzari the function itself looks fine with the implementation, are you sure where you declare/use your function, that you are supplying lists with data inside? Can you try to debug it and check that? Because with partial code its hard to pin-point the source of the additional issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236971/discussion-between-michelangelo-amoruso-manzari-and-zaid-al-shattle).